# Is NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest without any context, safe to fetch _objectIDs_

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

We have a background thread that needs to do some fetching.. but it doesnt need any data -- only the objectIDs

originally we did this using a specific newly created blank managed context just for this.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [DKDocumentDetails requestAllWithPredicate:predicate inContext:ctx];
[request setResultType:NSManagedObjectIDResultType];
self.objectIDs = [DKDocumentDetails executeFetchRequest:request inContext:ctx];
...
```

but recently I found out, I can also do this on the PST itself, without any context **AS I dont want Managed Objects, but only IDs**

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [DKDocumentDetails requestAllWithPredicate:predicate inContext:mainctx /*used in the wrong thread but only for getting entity description*/];
[request setResultType:NSManagedObjectIDResultType];

NSError *error = nil;
self.objectIDs = [pst executeRequest:request inContext:nil error:&error];
...
```

so in my tests it never crashed and in the docs I dont see why it shouldnt work either... I mean I dont get unsaved stuff and I cannot get objects, but used this way...

It is faster and looks elegant but is it safe or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been thinking about your question all day. Here is what I've come up with. As others have pointed out, `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` objects are not thread safe. When a bunch of `NSManagedObjectContext` objects on various threads use the same `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`, they do so by locking and unlocking the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.

However, you are worried about just reading data, and thread safe `NSManagedObjectID` data at that. Is that ok?

Well, the [Apple documentation On Concurrency with Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1) mentions something similar to what you are doing:

> For example, you can configure a fetch request to return just object IDs but also include the row data (and update the row cache)—this can be useful if you're just going to pass those object IDs from a background thread to another thread.

Ok, but do we need to lock the Coordinator?

> There is typically no need to use locks with managed objects or managed object contexts. However, if you use a single persistent store coordinator shared by multiple contexts and want to perform operations on it (for example, if you want to add a new store), or if you want to aggregate a number of operations in one context together as if a virtual single transaction, you should lock the persistent store coordinator.

That seems to be pretty clear that if you are performing operations on a persistent store from more than one thread, you should lock it.

But wait - these are just read operations, shouldn't they be safe? Well, apparently not:

> Core Data does not present a situation where reads are “safe” but changes are “dangerous”—every operation is “dangerous” because every operation has cache coherency effects and can trigger faulting.

Its the cache we need to worry about. That's why you need to lock - a read in one thread can cause data in another thread to get messed up through inadvertent cache changes. Your code never gave you problems because this is probably really rare. But its those edge cases and 1-in-1,000,000 bugs that can do the most damage...

So, is it safe? My answer:

- If nothing else is using your persistent store coordinator while you read, yes, you are safe.
- If you have anything else using the same persistent store coordinator, then lock it before you get the object IDs.
- Using a managed object context means the locking is automatically taken care of for you, so its also a fine possibility, but it looks like you don't *need* to use it (and I agree it is nice to not make one just to get a few Object IDs).

Comment: this reads very good and you cite the docs to underline your points .. and layed out like this I think it qualifies as valid answer :) thanks :)

Comment: I will lock (just to be on the safe side :D)

Comment: where will use and why will use the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator        --------------------thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

From the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator docs:

> Note that if multiple threads work directly with a coordinator, they need to lock and unlock it explicitly.

I would say that if you were to properly lock the PSC:

```
[pst lock];
self.objectIDs = [pst executeRequest:request inContext:nil error:&error];
[pst unlock];
```

That would be considered "safe" according to my reading of the docs. That being said, locking done internally by the MOC might be the most significant performance difference between the two approaches you have described, and if that's the case you might prefer to to just use the blank MOC as it would be less surprising when you or someone else encounter's the code later.

Related question:
[Is NSPersistentStoreCoordinator Thread Safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976020/is-nspersistentstorecoordinator-thread-safe)

Answer (score 1):

There is no a good reason to NOT use a managed object context for this. The managed object context buys you a lot - it handles change management, threading, etc. etc. Using the persistent store coordinator directly loses a lot of this functionality. For example, if you have changes that have not been persisted yet to this store, you may miss them by using the persistent store coordinator directly.

Now you say the reason this is attractive to you is that you only want the managed object IDs.  What it seems you really want is to find managed objects but not fire faults on them. You can do this with either a NSManagedObjectResultType or a NSManagedObjectIDResultType on your fetch request. In the case of the NSManagedObjectResultType, you would just access the objectID on your fetched objects, which will not fire a fault - thus not "getting data". This can have some performance advantages if the row cache is already populated, etc.

With all of that said, why not just use parent-child contexts to solve this?

Comment: well I dont want to fire faults ... thats right but I dont want the objects at all... I dont need ANYTHING the context brings to the table either. :D

Comment: the point is mainly: I dont want to incur the overhead of a managedobject context. well.. I dont fear a performance issue of course but it seems ... natural to me to *ask the PST for the IDs* :D -- I get the feeling I am alone with this though ^^

Comment: Once you have implemented locking, etc. on the persistent store the difference in "overhead" is going to be about the same, and will probably be in favor of using a managed object context. Having implemented persistent stores before, I can tell you that your solution can have stability issues when in a user's hands.

Comment: But to answer your original question: "Is NSPersistentStoreCoordinator  executeRequest:withContext:error: without a context safe to fetch objects IDs" more directly, ..... no, not without a lot of extra work. This work is what the managed object context provides, which you would be circumventing.