# iOS Core Data fetch in background causing crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsfetchrequest

In my app I am constantly doing Core Data work in the background.

Testflight has been reporting a lot of crashes on a specific fetch which gets the current logged in environment object from Core Data (I cannot replicate):

```
- (Environment *)getActiveEnvironment
{
    AppDelegate *ad = [AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSConfinementConcurrencyType];
    [context setParentContext:ad.managedObjectContext];
    
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Environment" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    
    NSError *error;

    //crash points to this line
    NSArray *items = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    
    Environment *tempE = nil;
    if(items.count > 0)
    {
        for(Environment *e in items)
        {
            if(!e.token && !e.url)
            {
                break;
            }
            
            Environment *mainContextTv = (Environment *)[ad.managedObjectContext objectWithID:e.objectID];
            if(e.activeValue)
                 tempE = mainContextTv;                
        }  
    }

    return tempE;
}
```

Here is the crash stack I am receiving from Testflight:

```
0   Tower-iSales-Tab    0x002b37b2  testflight_backtrace
1   Tower-iSales-Tab    0x002b2e4a  TFSignalHandler
2   libsystem_platform.dylib    0x39144722  _sigtramp
3   CoreData    0x2e1b8cec  _perform
4   CoreData    0x2e1c30f4  -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:]
5   CoreData    0x2e13477a  -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:]
6   Tower-iSales-Tab    0x000c7082  -[MySingleton getActiveEnvironment] in MySingleton.m on Line 379
7   Tower-iSales-Tab    0x000c73f8  -[MySingleton getToken] in MySingleton.m on Line 416
8   Tower-iSales-Tab    0x0020c476  -[NetworkManager getPathForViewName:useTimeStamp:timeStamp:index:counter:] in NetworkManager.m on Line 699
9   Tower-iSales-Tab    0x0020aa5a  __70-[NetworkManager checkForDataFilesShouldEmptyQueue:isInitialDownload:]_block_invoke167 in NetworkManager.m on Line 415
10  libdispatch.dylib   0x3901b8fa  _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke
11  Tower-iSales-Tab    0x0020a33e  __70-[NetworkManager checkForDataFilesShouldEmptyQueue:isInitialDownload:]_block_invoke113 in NetworkManager.m on Line 335
12  libdispatch.dylib   0x39017102  _dispatch_call_block_and_release
13  libdispatch.dylib   0x3901c7e4  _dispatch_root_queue_drain
14  libdispatch.dylib   0x3901c9d0  _dispatch_worker_thread2
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x39146dfe  _pthread_wqthread
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x39146cc3  start_wqthread
```

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14076685/480415) which suggests to set the queue type to `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`, not `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` which I can do, but this is not a crash I can replicate easily so i'd like to know for sure that would cause this crash.

That answer also suggest using the `performBlockAndWait` block for background fetches, but in my function how would I? I need to return an `Environment` object, I use this function all over my app.

Thanks

Comment: Is `-getActiveEnvironment` running on the background thread?

Comment: I just looked through my calls and no it is not always getting called in a dispatch block. I assume that could cause some issues.. I believe the crash is happening when core data is already sycning in the background, and I call this from the main thread? but I am not sure

Comment: But is it sometimes running on the background thread (e.g. called from `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)`?

Comment: Actually I take that back sorry, I am not calling it from any dispatch blocks. I store the current environment has a local variable, then that in the background. But, I need to have the fetch happen in the background to avoid any locks ups on the main context.. if that makes sense..

Comment: OK, so you're calling `-getActiveEnvironment` only from the main thread, store the result as a local variable. Are you sure you're not using this object later from the different thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you don't have to use `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` context here, as you're calling `-getActiveEnvironment` only from the main thread. So you can do all operations on the main context (`ad.managedObjectContext`).

The returned object should then be accessed only from the main thread. If you want to access it from some other thread you have to use `objectWithID:` to get it in the context associated with that thread.

Comment: I am going to try this out and see if the # of crashes diminishes. The reason I was not using ad.managedObjectContext is because if the app is syncing, and you press a button that calls getActiveEnvironment, it pauses the background syncing for a second as the UI hangs. I can live with that though if it will prevent the crashing. Thanks will keep you updated when I get some testing data

Comment: I am now calling this function from my  main thread (using my main store context), which does not interfere with the with the background processing. I have not seen the crash appear since I made the change. I recommend this as well article for anyone who is having core data issues, its old but still useful: http://www.duckrowing.com/2010/03/11/using-core-data-on-multiple-threads/

Answer (score 2):

In all likelihood, the cause of this problem is that you're accessing the `NSManagedObjectContext` from a different thread to that in which it was created..

**Golden rule: always access an `NSManagedObjectContext` from the thread you created it in.**

So you need to make sure your MOC is being accessed consistently from the same thread.

I believe the `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` stuff may be incidentally related and doing that may fix the problem (depending on what else your code is doing exactly), but it's likely not to be the core issue here.

Side note: the persistent object store doesn't have the same requirement and is thread-safe (often you have multiple MOCs using the same persistent object store).

Comment: Thanks. I ended up created a separate NSPersistentStoreCoordinator for my background thread, and things are running smoother.

Comment: The PSC is actually thread safe, so you shouldn't have to do this. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976020/is-nspersistentstorecoordinator-thread-safe

Comment: Well I watched a session on Core Data from this years WWDC and they recommended having a seperate NSPersistentStoreCoordinator's for large data processing in the background-- then use the main NSPersistentStoreCoordinator for the UI. I adapted to this and like I said it seems to be working better. It could also be working better because I was doing something wrong when I was only use 1 NSPersistentStoreCoordinator